# Probability of Multiple Choice first attempt and second attempt

Tags: probability

A multiple choice question has 5 available options, only 1 of which is correct. Students are allowed 2 attempts at the answer. A student who does not know the answer decides to guess at random, as follows:

On the first attempt, he guesses at random among the 5 options. If his guess is right, he stops. If his guess is wrong, then on the second attempt he guesses at random from among the 4 remaining options. Find the chance that the student gets the right answer at his first attempt? Then, find the chance the student has to make two attempts and gets the right answer the second time?Find the chance that the student gets the right answer?

$P(k)=nk\times p^k\times({1−p})^n−k$.

$P($First attempt to get right answer$)=(5C_1)\times \frac{1}{5} \times (\frac{2}{4})^4=?$

$P($Second attempt to get right answer$)=(5C_2)\times \frac{1}{5}\times (\frac{2}{4})^3=?$

$P($The student gets it right$)=(5C_1)\times \frac{1}{5} \times (\frac{2}{4})^4=?$

Comment: It is best to not go to formulas too quickly: the probability of being right on the first try is $1/5$.

Comment: if the Probability first try agreed is 1/5 then the second what is it..(1/5)*(2/4). What is the probability of right(100% or 1)??? Andre Nicolas?

Comment: @statistics-student13: there is no repetition after guessing the correct answer.

Comment: To do it the long way, the probability she is wrong on the first try is $(4/5)$. **Given** that she is wrong on the first, the probability she is right on the second is $(1/4)$, since she is certainly not going to repeat her wrong guess. So the desired probability is $(4/5)(1/4)=1/5$. In my answer, I get the $1/5$ without calculation.

Comment: THANKS ITS VERY-VERY CLEAR AT LAST WHAT IS CHANCE OF GETTING RIGHT THAT IS the chance that the student gets the right answer?

Answer (score 1):

The probability that the student gets the right answer the first time is $\frac{1}{5}$. For there are $5$ possible first guesses, only $1$ of which is right.

There is a long (well, not that long) way of doing the second problem. Let's do it quickly. Imagine that the student has prepared a list of guesses in advance. The probability that the right answer is in first position among these guesses is exactly the same as the probability it is in the second position, the third, the fourth, the fifth: they are all $\frac{1}{5}$.

So the probability that she is  wrong on the first and right on the second is $\frac{1}{5}$. If more guessing were allowed, the probability she is wrong on the first two guesses, and right on the third, is again $\frac{1}{5}$. And so on.

Comment: Explain The Probability of the Second is also (1/5)*(1/5)??? Andre Nicolas then Whats the Probability of third question of getting right?

Comment: I did **not** write what you quote. The answer says the probability the first is wrong and the second is right is $\frac{1}{5}$, exactly the same as the probability the first is right. And if she is allowed up to $3$ guesses, the probability the first two are wrong and the third right is again $\frac{1}{5}$.

Comment: NOW THE GUESS IS ONLY FIRST ATTEMPT AND SECOND ATTEMPT WHICH YOU CORRECTLY EXPLAINED. THIRD QUESTION IS Find the chance that the student gets the right answer INDEPENDENT OF FIRST TWO ATTEMPTS?Andre Nicolas!

Comment: It's OK, my eyesight is good enough that I don't need caps. The third question is not really properly posed. Is the question asking what is the probability the student gets the right answer? If so, it is $\frac{2}{5}$. If the question says the student makes independent **choices** on the two attempts, in other words possibly make the same guess twice in a row, the probability she gets the right answer is $\frac{9}{25}$. So what exactly is the third question in your list?

Comment: The Third Question omit word Independent was a bad comment my side so the Third question is The Probability the student gets right answer? Thanks Andre Nicolas?which is 2/5..Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

First try to find the sample space $S$ for the question. There are five equally likely choices, so $S=\{c_1,\cdots, c_5\}$ and the event $E \subset S$ is choosing the correct answer, and there is only one correct answer i.e. $|E|=1.$ Therefore the probability is $\frac{|E|}{|S|}=\frac 15.$

Do the same to determine the sample space for the second question and find the relevant event. What is the answer, then?

Comment: so The Probability of the second (1/5)*(1/5)?